# Send huge data from client to server

Tags: go, grpc

I am working with `Go` and `Grpc`. I have one `XML` file to be sent from client to server. When server calls a method on client, client responds back with an `XML` document which could range from few `kB` to 100s `MB` or may be more. Please help me with how should I do it? Should I

1. assign the value to a `string` variable and send normally -> `rpc GetCMData (CmRequest) returns (CmReply) {}`
2. assign the value to a `string` variable and send as a `stream` -> `rpc GetCMData (CmRequest) returns (stream CmReply) {}`
3. Is there any other better way to do so?

This is how `CmReply` looks like:

```
message CmReply {
  string name = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one is more the way you want to go. But another point: Are you sure you want to have these hundreds of megabytes in your RAM? I'm not the Go-Geek, but I generally would prefer to work on a File Stream. And probably implement something like a back-pressure-system.

If you work with streams: I would also implement something to make sure that you can handle a break of the stream. Let's say you have the half of your stream and the stream breaks. You don't want to start again and get all previous stream elements, which you already have on the client side. You risk again a connection break within the stream. Maybe at the same point. So, something like pagination. Let's say

```
message CMRequest{
  int startAt = 0;
}

message CmReply {
  string id = 0;
  string name = 1;
}
```

If the stream breaks, you send a new request with startAt= LastCmReply.id+1

Here's a video of some good practices in grpc: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_yD7YPL2oE&index=17&list=WL

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Implement client-side streaming protocol in the way you have described above (split your file into chunks and send them one-by-one to the server):
   https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/issues/414#issuecomment-284515856
2. Extend the default `4 MB` limits for a message size for your `GRPC` client and server (then you'll be able to send and receive big messages without streaming):
   https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#MaxMsgSize
   https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#WithMaxMsgSize